# How is an invalid return type of main() handled by the OS?

Tags: c

I started programming with following definition of `main()`

```
void main(){}
```

Then somebody told me that this format of main() is bad programming because it should return int. He also told me that following definitions of main() are valid in C.

```
int main(void){}
```

or

```
int main(int argc,int *argv[]){}
```

Today I tried to experiment with other data types and surprisingly all the following compiles without errors.

```
char main(){}

float main(){}

int* main(){}
```

and even this compiles successfully

```
struct Abc{
int a;
};

struct Abc* main(){}
```

So my questions regarding this are following:

- How does the OS deal with these unexpected return types? [I am asking this because I think return value of `main()` is used by OS]
- Why is `main()` allowed to return any type?
- Why do compiler designers make this so flexible by saying *"`main()` should return int"* I think there would be  no problem if they said *"`main()` must return int"*?

Comment: So no, the return value of main is not generally "used by the OS".

Comment: @fast: Yes, it certainly is used by the OS, or at least made available by the OS. On UNIX-like systems, after executing a program from the shell its return value is available as `$?`, which is used for flow control. Windows behaves similarly.

Comment: I think the question originated in the expectation, that the OS likes to interpret the return value of main in some certain way; which i still would say it does not (although yes, interpreting and propagating it as int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the return type of `main` is not either `int` or some implementation-defined type (where "implementation-defined" means that it's *documented* by the implementation), the behavior is undefined.

That means that a compiler is not required to issue a warning or error message, but the C standard says *nothing* about how the program behaves.

The actual behavior depends on the compiler (calling conventions, etc.) and on the operating system.

In many cases, the value returned by `main` (if any) will simply be interpreted as if it were an `int`. If it returns a `double` with the value `1.0`, it *might* be equivalent to returning an `int` value 1065353216.

Or the compiler might reject it at compile time. Or your program might crash. As far as the C standard is concerned, literally *anything* can happen.

There are a lot of coding errors in C that compilers are not required to detect or to handle in any particular way. In such cases, it's entirely up to the programmer to get things right.

Just use the correct declaration. For hosted implementations, use either

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

(For freestanding (embedded) implementations, the declaration is entirely implementation-defined, and the entry point may or may not be called `main`; consult your compiler's documentation.)

As for why declaring `main` incorrectly doesn't require a diagnostic, I'm not entirely sure. It does make things slightly simpler for compiler writers. They can treat `main` just like any other function. There are *some* non-standard forms that are actually useful; for example, UNIX-like systems sometimes permit

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp) { /* ... */ }
```

where the third argument provides access to environment variables. I personally would prefer it if incorrect definitions of `main` had to be diagnosed.

This is also discussed in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), starting at question 11.12a.

Comment: thanks, so again it is undefined behavior ,how many things are there in C which are undefined

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar: A whole heck of a lot. Annex J, subsection 2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (that's a PDF of the N1570 draft of C11) lists *some* of the instances of undefined behavior; the list is more than 12 pages long. But more generally, any behavior not defined by the standard is undefined; section 4 paragraph 2 says so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The OS expects return value of type `int` and gets it from the default place (e.g. register `EAX`). If you return other type, the OS will get value of `EAX` again. Nothing special.